# Microsecond simulation time step for stageros

Tags: ros, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking into some sample .world files, I can see that interval_sim value can be set in milliseconds. It seems to be working fine for 100 ms. But when I make it 0.1 ms, it doesn't seem to be running that fast. I am publishing strings via ros topics (by changing  code in stageros.cpp) to test how fast it can publish. Either ros publishing or stageros cannot seem to cross the millisec boundary.

Any suggestions, experiences, fixes regarding running stageros simulation (without gui) in the microseconds range?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103696/microsecond-simulation-time-step-for-stageros/) by [devesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4103/devesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2013-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this is pretty late, but it's worth a shot. Stageros interval time is the rate at which it simulates physics and sensors in the simulation. The ROS nodes running generally think that simulated ROS time is true time, so they see everything as if it is acting full speed. On the other hand, the simulation will run very slowly in real time because it is taking the computer a long time to calculate everything it needs to for each .1 millisecond. If you are looking for the simulation to run closer to real time as you see it, I found that 1 ms is about as fast as I can go on my machine.

---

Originally posted by [buckbaskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/21301/buckbaskin/) with karma: 16 on 2016-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-04-27**:
just a couple of years =), I am marking your answer as correct and closing the question, as it seems quite valid to me... cheers